# Casting from ArrayList<Object> to List<HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,String>>>

Tags: java, casting, nested-generics

I am having trouble casting from `ArrayList<Object>` to `List<HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,String>>>` as demonstrated in the following

code:

```
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> l1 =
                new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> l2 =
                new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();

        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(l1);
        list.add(l2);

        List <HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>> myList = (List<HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>>) list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not declare `list` already as `List<HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>>`?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

with

```
List <HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(l1);
list.add(l2);
```

Else, do the following:

```
List <HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>> myList = new ArrayList();
for (Object obj : list) {
    myList.add((HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>) obj);
}
```

Comment: Why encourage the use of raw types?

Comment: I don't have that option, as the method I am overriding returns List <Object>.  Particularly, the [getCrawlersLocalData](http://javadox.com/edu.uci.ics/crawler4j/4.1/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/CrawlController.html#getCrawlersLocalData--)  method of class CrawlController.

Comment: @PhoenixOpenProject Then please edit the question, as your current code snippet is misleading.

Comment: @PankajSinghal As you and user YCF_L user have pointed out, I must cast element by element, unless I use features in Java 1.8 (or above).  To help me better understand the problem, why can't I directly cast rom ArrayList<Object> to List<HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,String>>> when the underlying element objects are in  fact of type HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,String>> ?

Comment: @PankajSinghal I tried your 2nd solution, but the compiler reported an "unchecked cast from Object to HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>" warning.

Comment: Yeah, the warning would be there, but it would work just fine. If you want to avoid the warning, use the first solution

Comment: @PankajSinghal there are two important lessons I learned through this problem: 1)  casts to generic classes are unchecked. 2) More than one level of generics should be avoided. (Someone suggested that I should at least create a class with a meaningful name for the value)